# Swift 1.2 -> 2.0: Invalid bitcast

Tags: compiler-errors, swift2

after my update to Swift 2.0 I get the following error:

**Invalid bitcast
i8* bitcast (i64 ptrtoint ([5 x i8]* @14 to i64) to i8*)
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!**

There is an error during the compilation. So I can't set Breakpoints or do anything.
As I understand it fails during a convertation from a pointer to and integer... But how could I find out where it could be?

Did anyone have something similar and found a solution?
I'm happy for every idea.

Comment: having the same problem. Did you end up identifying the issue?